# GUI to check for prime numbers

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, boolean

I have updated the code to reflect the BigInteger num. But I am now receiving errors with my display message. Syntax error is under IsPrime. How can I change this string output to get the correct display message to the user? Here is my code:

```
         public static void main (String [] args){
    //prompt user to input a number

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "); 
    // change string to int
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input); 

    //display message to user of their results
        BigInteger num = new BigInteger(input); 

        String output = number + " is" + (BigInteger(input) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number: " + BigInteger(input);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, output);

}   



public static Boolean IsPrime(BigInteger num) {
    // check if number is a multiple of 2
    if (num.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
      return false;
    }// if not, then just check the odds
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(num) <= 0; i =
        i.add(new BigInteger("2"))) {
      if (num.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {

       return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

}

Comment: The names of methods and variables begin in lower case by convention (as opposite to class names). Going into your problem, to begin with, you never call `IsPrime(int)`.

Comment: break the loop once `IsPrime` is false. Follow the java naming convention.

Comment: What is the mean of `+num`? Does is make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your IsPrime method takes a big int - but does all the checking with standard ints - that's going to cause problems if your user wants to be difficult.  This is working code for checking prime numbers for general BigIntegers.

```
  public static Boolean IsPrime(BigInteger num) {
        // check if number is a multiple of 2
        if (num.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
          return false;
        }// if not, then just check the odds
        for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(num) <= 0; i =
            i.add(new BigInteger("2"))) {
          if (num.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {

           return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: How can I change the following to have an output that reflects the new BigInteger code?     String output = number + " is" + (IsPrime(number) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number: " + IsPrime(number);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to check for prime number

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i=2;2*i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

A more faster way to check for prime number

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n%2==0) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

--EDIT--

As per your updated question and comments

Try this one

```
String output = number + " is" + (isPrime(number) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number.";
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I am now having issues displaying the correct "is a prime number" when its a prime number and "is not a prime number" when it is not a prime. The code is displaying the "is a prime number every time no matter what the number is. Here is what I have: String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "); 

         int number = Integer.parseInt(input); 


                String output = number + " is a prime number: " + IsPrime(number);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, output);

Comment: You code will work fine. just use method defined in my post. Is there any issue?

Comment: Ok let me do it for you

Comment: the code reflected the correct true/false response but is still defalting to "is a prime number" no matter what number I input. Do I need to add an additional String output?

Comment: Try this one `String output = number + " is" + (IsPrime(number) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number: ";`

Comment: You are a true blessing!! Thank you so much! I have been working on this for two days to no avail. Now how would I Use the BigInteger (java.math.BigInteger) class instead of regular integers??

Comment: Try in this way `BigInteger number = new BigInteger(input)`. but you have to change your `isPrime()` method also.

Comment: Use `long` instead of `BigInteger`.

Comment: I have updated the code and am receiving several errors. Here is the code:  public static Boolean IsPrime(BigInteger num) { 

 
      //check if number is a multiple of 2
      if (num%2==0) return false;
      //if not, then just check the odds
      for(int i=3;i*i<=num;i+=2) {
          if(num%i==0)

Comment: Use `long` or `int` in place of `BigInteger` if possible. I have already mentioned it in my last post.

Comment: I am having to set it up using public static Boolean IsPrime(BigInteger num) thats why I have updated the code reflecting that

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What you want to achieve? What the problem in my posted code. Why you can't use it. Try in this way `public static Boolean IsPrime(int num)`

Comment: Please update you post along with complete code to make it more clear to me.

Comment: The previous way did work. I am also supposed to get the program to work using the public static Boolean IsPrime (BigInteger num). All of the rest of the code is the same except needing to now change the code to reflect the BigInteger num.

Comment: Please post you complete code in your question itself. So that I can modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: First tell me one thing. You are passing `int` in `IsPrime` method then why you can't change the method signature to `public static Boolean IsPrime(int num)`. Your problem will be solved. Please tell me the range of number that user can input?

Comment: I was just advised that I would need to change the code to reflect public static boolean IsPrime (BigInteger num). There would be no range of numbers. The user would be allow to input their number and the program should check if it is prime using biginteger.

Comment: Go ahead with @Joe answer.

Comment: Just do one change when calling this method `BigInteger number = new BigInteger(input)`. and just call `IsPrime(number)`.

Comment: I made that change but the output is only telling the user that the number is prime regardless of the number that was inputted. How can I get the display message to change?

Comment: As per your updated code you are not calling `IsPrime()` method any where. Please look into it again.